# find t so that U + W = $\mathbb R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following vectors
$$ u_1 = (1, t, 2t, 0)^T,
u_2 = (t, t, t, t)^T,
v_1 = (t - 2, -t, -3t, t)^T,
v_2 = (2, t, 2t, 0)^T
$$

and

$$ U = span\{u_1, u_2\} , V = span\{v_1, v_2\} $$

And I am to find a $t$ so that $U + V = \mathbb R^4$

To be honest I'm not entirely sure where to start. I have tried to understand the definition of $U + V$ but what I'm unsure of is if I have to add every vector in $U$ with every vector in $V$ so that

\begin{align*}U + V &= span\{u_1 + v_1, u_1 + v_2, u_2 + v_1, u_2 + v_2\} \\
         &=span\{(t-1, 0, -t, t)^T, (3, 2t, 4t, 0)^T, (2t-2, 0, -2t, 2t)^T, (t+2, 2t, 3t, t)^T\}
\end{align*} and then put that into a matrix and more or less solve for t, or if I have perhaps completely misunderstood what $U + V$ actually means.

Comment: Surely you’re interested in $U=span\{u_1,u_2\}$? As currently written $U$ and $V$ are finite sets!

Comment: Yep, you're correct. My mistake. I'll edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We define the **direct sum** of two vector spaces, $U,V$, denoted $U+V$ or $U\oplus V$ to be be the set $W$ such that $W=\{w=u+v:u\in U,v\in V\}$. In words, this set is what you get when you take each element of $U$ and add it to each element of $V$.

It is a fact about direct sums that if $G_U$ generates $U$ and $G_V$ generates $V$ then $G_{U+V}=G_U\cup G_V$ generates $U+V$. Therefore you’re interested in finding the values of $t$ such that $span\{u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2\}=\mathbb R^4$

Comment: And im I correct in assuming that the only stipulation for my t is that it has to make sure that every row does not equal 0? So that every dimension in R4 is covered?

Comment: @user25758 You’re right in spirit, but you have the wrong requirement. Yes you need every dimension to be covered, but the requirement is that all four rows are linearly independent, not that they are non-zero.

Comment: Of course. Thanks very much, that makes more sense.